# Ajax en servidor express JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Buen Dia,
tengo un servidor en javascript express con el cual despliego un servidor websocket.

Ahora necesito que al recibir una señal por el websocket me envie ese dato a un PHP, he investigado y la mejor opción es enviarlo por ajax pero al incluir esa linea me genera el siguiente error

> ```
> $.ajax({
>  ^ReferenceError: $ is not defined
> at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\app.js:25:6)
> at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
> at C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:528:12
> at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
> ```

Por lo que tengo que incluir la libreria de JQuery al Javascript file pero no se como lo pueda incluir.

El codigo completo del server express es el siguiente.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var server = app.listen(3000,'0.0.0.0',function(){
    console.log("App server up and running on %s and port %s",server.address().address ,server.address().port);
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.emit('welcome_event', { info: 'world' });

    socket.on('response_evet',function(data){
      //Que guarde en un txt en la misma ruta de este archivo
      /*El objeto param contendrá los datos que mandarás al servidor para procesarlos*/
     var param = {
         mensaje: data
     };

     $.ajax({
        data: param,
        url: "saveFile.php",
        method: "post",
        success: function(data) {
          /*La variable data contiene la respuesta de tu script PHP*/
        }
     });

     console.log("Data desde el cliente",data);
    });
});
```

Como podria incluir el Ajax en este archivo, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Inluyelo, descargándolo desde NPM, del modo siguiente

```
npm install -S jquery
```

Posteriormente en tu archivo `js` simplemente lo requieres de este modo

```
const jquery = require('jquery')
```

Si deseas verificar la instalación, manda a imprimir desde consola la constante recién creada de este modo:

```
console.log(jquery)
```

Lo cual te devuelve un mensaje similar a este:

```
[Function]
```

Ya con eso deberías tener para que sirva dentro de tu archivo

Aquí la fuente original

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

Comment: Me sigue generando un error por el signo ($)

Answer (score 0):

en vez de Ajax con jquery, podes usar Fetch que es la manera de hacerlo sin jquery y es muy simple de usar:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch